# Add minutes to an input field and display hours/mins

Tags: jquery, time

I have a simple input field that allows users to enter the number of minutes they have worked for that day. Is there a way that once they have entered the details into this field i can have a display next to the input displaying the time in hours and minutes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var m = $('#input').val();
var hours = Math.floor(m / 60);
m = m % 60;

$('#someDiv').text('hours: ' + hours + 'minutes: ' + m);
```

Comment: +1, but it should be `$('#someDiv').text('hours: ' + parseInt(hours) + 'minutes: ' + m);`, without `parseInt` it shows `hours: 1.1666666666666667minutes: 10` for `70`.

Comment: @SheikhHeera, thanks, I didn't think on the decimal point. I preferred `Math.floor` though.

Comment: `Math.floor` is Better than that.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this to get the hours/minutes in the format `hh:mm`:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="mins" />
<span id="hm"></span>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#mins').change(function(){
    var h = Math.floor( $('#mins').val() / 60);
    h = "0" + h;
    h = h.substr(h.length - 2, 2);
    var m = Math.floor( $('#mins').val() % 60);
    m = "0" + m;
    m = m.substr(m.length - 2, 2);

    $('#hm').html(h + ':' +m);
});
```

[**Jsfiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/bwu5E/)

Answer (score 0):

Some simple math and formatting should get you there.

```
function getTimeStringFromMinutes(m) {
    var hours = Math.floor(m/60);
    var seconds = (m - Math.floor(m)) * 60;
    minutes = Math.floor(m % 60);
    var output = (hours < 10 ? '0'+hours : hours) + 
                 ":" + 
                 (minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes) + 
                 ":" + 
                 (seconds < 10 ? '0'+seconds : seconds);
    return output;
}
// getTimeStringFromMinutes(128.5) --> "02:08:30"
// getTimeStringFromMinutes('128.5') --> "02:08:30"
```

(PS don't be scared of the ternary operators they are simply dynamic values in the form of: *condition : valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse*)